# C++ algorithm in iOS application

Tags: c++, objective-c, algorithm, ios5

I've got a DSP audio aglo in C# that I'd like to incorporate into iOS. A friend suggested that I convert to C++ instead of Objective-C, as it would be platform agnostic. Is this a good practice, any pitfalls to be aware of? My instinct is to keep it native with Obj-C. How would I access C++ functions within iOS?

Thank you

Comment: The only truly cross-platform lang is C89, and I can guarantee you don't want to rewrite it in that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can freely mix C++ with Objective-C, it's known as "Objective-C++". To let the compiler know that is your intent, you need to rename you `.m` file as `.mm`.

Mixing code like that is not necessarily a good idea, and fairly pointless if you aim is portability. Better is to keep you C++ in separate `.cpp` files, and create a bare-bones wrapper class (obj-c++) to pass data between your objective-C and C++ objects (effectively the wrapper is mediating obj-C methods and C++ functions to send and return data).

I have recently posted a couple of simple image processing examples of this on github - [openCVSquares](https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVSquares) and [openCVStitch](https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVStitch). It's worth you taking a look, just to see how the C++ code is separated out from obj-C.

The openCV libraries have a C++ interface, so using C++ in the project is unavoidable. It *would* be possible to mash all of the code into .mm files, but that's an easy way to make a mess.

As regards portability, you get this by separating your UI code from your data-manipulation code. You should be doing this anyway for MVC, so it will be little additional work to write your model in C++ as per these examples.  The *model* is portable, the *UI* is - and should be - platform specific.

Whether *you* should do this will depend on other factors such as your fluency with each language, the choice of frameworks and libraries, and the likelihood of porting. Audio processing would be a natural candidate for such an approach though.

*Some detail about the samples*
Don't worry if you can't get the code to run (the openCV framework can be troublesome...) the main thing is to see how the code is pieced together. I've tried to keep the examples very simple.

The C++ code was ported from C++ samples included with the openCV distro: [squares.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/squares.cpp) and [stitching.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching.cpp). I tried to alter these as little as possible in order to assess this idea of portability.

Roughly, I had to address two issues...
1/ removed any UI code (so we are just sending data back to the obj-C side).
2/ modify the main() function so it becomes a callable function from the obj-C side. In the .cpp header file I declare a simple class with a single static function to facilitate this. Obviously there is scope to get much more elaborate but this should be enough for you to get the idea.

Comment: Thank you much. Very informative, I will study the examples you reference on github.